# How to build a simple moving average measure

Tags: activepivot, atoti

I want to build a measure to get the simple moving average for each day. I have a cube with a single table containing stock market information.

Schema
[image: Schema]

The expected result is that for each date, this measure shows the closing price average of the X previous days to that date.

For example, for the date 2013-02-28 and for X = 5 days, this measure would show the average closing price for the days 2013-02-28, 2013-02-27, 2013-02-26, 2013-02-25, 2013-02-22. The closing values of those days are summed, and then divided by 5.
**The same would be done for each of the rows.**

Example dashboard
[image: Example dashboard]

Maybe it could be achieved just with the function `tt..agg.mean()` but indicating those X previous days in the scope parameter.

The problem is that I am not sure how to obtain the X previous days for each of the dates dynamically so that I can use them in a measure.

Answer (score 0):

You can compute a sliding average you can use the cumulative scope as referenced in the atoti documentation https://docs.atoti.io/latest/lib/atoti.scope.html#atoti.scope.cumulative.

By passing a tuple containing the date range, in your case `("-5D", None)` you will be able to calculate a sliding average over the past 5 days for each date in your data.

The resulting Python code would be:

```
import atoti as tt
// session setup
...
m, l = cube.measures, cube.levels
// measure setup
...
tt.agg.mean(m["ClosingPrice"], scope=tt.scope.cumulative(l["date"], window=("-5D", None)))
```